# nmap Scripting Engine checking for running Ident Service RFC 1413

Tags: service, lua, port, nmap

I am trying to create a lua script for the nmap scripting engine that reads a list of IPs from a file and checks those hosts for a running Ident Service on port 113. The issue with the following script is that it does not seem to finish, even though the only IP in the file is the one of another VM running on my system.

```
local stdnse = require "stdnse"

local targets = stdnse.get_script_args('targets')
local ports = "113"
local services = {}

-- Portscan with SYN-Scan (-sS)
local portstate = {}

for target in io.lines(targets) do
  local result = nmap.scan({target}, ports, "-sS")
  portstate[target] = result[target].tcp
end

-- Output of the results
for target, ports in pairs(portstate) do
  if ports then
    stdnse.print_output(target .. ":")
    for port, state in pairs(ports) do
      stdnse.print_output("  Port " .. port .. "/" .. state.state)
    end
  else
    stdnse.print_output(target .. ":")
    stdnse.print_output("  No open ports found.")
  end
end
```

The file is saved as .nse file and then executed via:
`nmap --./TestScript.nse -p 113 -iL ./IPList.txt`

Any help to find an improved script would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried using SYN scans for improved performance, however this did not have any effect